# Editing a MultiString Array for a registry value in Powershell

Tags: list, powershell, registry

How do I create a new MultiString Array and pass it to the registry remotely using Powershell 2.0?

```
#get the MultiLine String Array from the registry
$regArry = (Get-Itemproperty "hklm:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA" -name "Notification Packages").("Notification Packages")

#Create a new String Array
[String[]]$tempArry = @()

#Create an ArrayList from the Registry Array so I can edit it
$tempArryList = New-Object System.Collections.Arraylist(,$regArry)


# remove an entry from the list
if ( $tempArryList -contains "EnPasFlt" )
{   
    $tempArryList.Remove("EnPasFlt")
}


# Add an entry
if ( !($tempArryList -contains "EnPasFltV2x64"))
{
    $tempArryList.Add("EnPasFltV2x64")
}

# Convert the list back to a multi-line Array  It is NOT creating new Lines!!!
foreach($i in $tempArryList) {$tempArry += $1 = "\r\n"]}


# Remove the old Array from the Registry
(Remove-ItemProperty "hklm:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" -name "notification packages").("Notification Packages")

# Add the new one
New-itemproperty "hklm:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" -name "notification packages" -PropertyType MultiString -Value "$tempArry"
```

Everything works great except that i can't get the values to go to a new line.  I've tried `/r/n` and `'r'n`.  My output in the registry show everything on one line and adds the literal newline and carriage return flags that I add.  How do i get the Array to recognize these and not literally print them?

Comment: In your question you are using `'r'n` (apostrophe), but the character you need to use is backtick `\``, so `\`r\`n`. Can you confirm which one you were using?

Comment: Awesome!  i will try that.  Can you give me a plus one?  If you want you can answer the question and if it works I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for fiddling around with `ArrayList` and linebreaks. Particularly if you want to modify a remote registry. Simply use the [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```psh
$server = '...'

$subkey = 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA'
$value  = 'Notification Packages'

$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $server)
$key = $reg.OpenSubKey($subkey, $true)
$arr = $key.GetValue($value)

$arr = @($arr | ? { $_ -ne 'EnPasFlt' })
if ($arr -notcontains 'EnPasFltV2x64') {
  $arr += 'EnPasFltV2x64'
}

$key.SetValue($value, [string[]]$arr, 'MultiString')
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I highly recommend going this route instead of the other way.

Comment: Is this available in Powershell 2.0?  I truied this before and it wouldn't work.

Comment: @antman1p Define "wouldn't work". The above should work even with PowerShell v2 and .Net Framework 2.0.

Comment: I stand corrected.  It worked!  Thank you!  Much easier.  Can you give my question a plus please?

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell the escape character is a backtick " ` ", not an apostrophe `'`. So you would want to try this:

```powershell
foreach($i in $tempArryList) {$tempArry += $1 = "`r`n"]}
```

Backtick was likely chosen because a backslash `\` is a path separator in Windows.